# PostgreSQL : SQL timestamp to Unix timestamp using libpq

Tags: c++, c, postgresql

I know I can convert SQL timestamp to unix timestamp, using the following way.

```
SELECT extract(epoch FROM now());
```

Now, I have a stored procedure function, which will directly return a table row to the caller. One of the row field is "timestamp" type.

In my application, I am using libpq. I wish to use libpq functions (or any c/c++ function), to convert "2010-01-11 13:10:55.283" into unix timestamp. Off course, I can create another stored procedure named

```
SQLTimestamp2UnixTimestamp
SELECT extract(epoch FROM $1);
```

But I just wish to accomplish this task with a single c/c++ function call, without involving stored procedure.

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57694237/postgresql-timestamp-to-stdchrono-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boost::posix_time::ptime t(boost::posix_time::time_from_string(ts));
boost::posix_time::ptime start(boost::gregorian::date(1970,1,1)); 
boost::posix_time::time_duration dur = t - start; 
time_t epoch = dur.total_seconds();

long timestamp = static_cast<long>(epoch);
```

Comment: a solution with native c++ without boost library should be mark as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Why not simply (untested):

```
/* PostgreSQL sent "date" */
strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &result);
```

then

```
strftime(epoch, MAX, "%s", result);
/* print epoch */
```