# postgresql timestamp to std::chrono value

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, libpqxx

What is the appropriate way to work with the the postgresql datatype "timestamp without timezone" from c++ (libpqxx)? I haven't been able to find a way to do this yet.
I am restricted to the "timestamp without timezone" datatype in the postgresql and the environment is running utc time. I was hoping to find a mapping to a std::chrono::system_clock::time_point member but I can't find a such in libpqxx.

//s has a time_point var and r is a pqxx::result, r[0] is sensible

```
s.creationtime = r[0]["creationtime"].as<std::chrono::system_clock::time_point>();
```

Answer (score 0):

The C++20 spec introduces a family of `chrono::time_point`s called [`local_time`](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.local):

```
// [time.clock.local], local time
struct local_t {};
template<class Duration>
  using local_time  = time_point<local_t, Duration>;
using local_seconds = local_time<seconds>;
using local_days    = local_time<days>;
```

These `time_point`s represent a "timestamp without a timezone".

There exists a free, open-source preview of this C++20 library here:

https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date

which is currently in use by other projects around the globe.  This library has a few minor changes from the C++20 spec, such as putting everything in `namespace date` instead of `namespace std::chrono`.

Example program using this library:

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    int y = 2019;
    int m = 8;
    int d = 28;
    int H = 14;
    int M = 42;
    int S = 16;
    int US = 500'000;
    local_time<microseconds> lt = local_days{year{y}/m/d} + hours{H} +
                                  minutes{M} + seconds{S} + microseconds{US};
    std::cout << lt << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
2019-08-28 14:42:16.500000
```

Answer (score 0):

With help from boost:

```
s.creationtime = makeTimePoint(r[0]["creationtime"].as<string>());
```

makeTimePoint:

```
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point makeTimePoint(const std::string& s)
{
  using namespace boost::posix_time;
  using namespace std::chrono;

  const ptime ts = time_from_string(s);
  auto seconds = to_time_t(ts);
  time_duration td = ts.time_of_day();
  auto microseconds = td.fractional_seconds();
  auto d = std::chrono::seconds{seconds} + std::chrono::microseconds{microseconds};
  system_clock::time_point tp{duration_cast<system_clock::duration>(d)};
  return tp;
}
```